# USB 3.0 devices not using SuperSpeed

Tags: usb, usb-3

I've had this issue for a while but haven't yet figured out a way to fix it. **Every USB device** I connect to my PC *never* exceeds High-Speed connection speed, even when the device is SuperSpeed or SuperSpeedPlus.

Here is an example from `USBView`:

```
      ========================== Summary =========================
Vendor ID                : 0x04E8 (Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.)
Product ID               : 0x4001
USB Version              : 2.10
Port maximum Speed       : High-Speed (Companion Port 3-16 supports SuperSpeed)
Device maximum Speed     : SuperSpeedPlus
Device Connection Speed  : High-Speed
Self powered             : no
Demanded Current         : 500 mA
Used Endpoints           : 5
```

The device is connected using a USB 3.0 cable (C to A, the motherboard does not have type C ports).

There are no other USB hubs or USB cards added to the motherboard, other then the integrated USB controller, which does show up in `Device Manager` as "Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)," and the USB device does appear inside of it when viewing the hierarchical view ("Devices by Connection") in Device Manager.

Yes, I have tried this with every single USB port on my PC (front and back), and I've checked that the front panel connectors are actually plugged into a USB 3.0 header on the motherboard.

It is interesting that USBView does list 21 ports (16 to 21 being listed as "Companion Ports" which say they support USB 3.0 SuperSpeed. But regardless of which physical port I use, it will never be one of those, it will always be a port which does not support USB 3.0 but suggests a companion port is present which does support it.

Comment: USB3 connectors basically include USB2 on a few pins. So check with different cables; if you used the same cable for every port, and the cable is broken, the outcome will be exactly what you see. Also test with different USB3 devices, as the connector on the USB3 device may also be broken.

Comment: 3 years later, and the question is: What was the issue? The cables? Unclear from your question what types of cables you were using. As this [posted answer states](https://superuser.com/a/1755042/167207), you need to use USB 3.0 cables to get USB 3.0 speeds; you can’t use plain old USB 1.1/2.0 cables and expect USB 3.0 speed.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been a year, but I think I've found the reason for your issue

I had the same issue and I was testing different USB cables in different port. Eventually I found a USB 3.0 SuperSpeed cable, and here are my observations:

The port listed in USB view is *not* the same as the exterior ports that you have on your keyboard. I don't know what they do, but depending on which USB cable I plug into my computer, on the *same* exterior USB port, a different port number appears as used in the USB view.

For example, when I used my USB SuperSpeed cable and plugged it into the port, it displayed as using USB port 9, which supports USB 3, but when I plugged in a USB 2 cable into the *same* USB port, it said it was using port 4, which didn't support USB 3.

I actually have exactly the same device and product as you (a Samsung hard drive), and replicated the exact same USB detail tree when plugging in a USB 2 device (except it suggested different companion ports).

**TL;DR**: None of your cables are actually USB 3 cables, which is why your computer won't let you connect to your USB 3 ports.